# Spring data jpa CRUDRepository/ JPArepository saveall can not get id (non primary key)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am fetching data from FB marketing API and trying to save in DB. I am able to save data in the DB using `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository` -> `saveall` method, but when trying to fetch the `id` in response of `saveall`, **I am getting `id` as null**. When I see in the `h2-console`, able to see the auto increment value after the completion of transaction.

**Note**: `id` is not used as primary key `@Id`.  `accountId` is used as primary key.

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
@Data
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Account implements Serializable{
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment",insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("account_id")
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    @Id
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name = "account_status")
    private int accountStatus;
    @JsonProperty("timezone_id")
    @Column(name = "timezone_id")
    private int timezoneId;
    private int timezoneOffsetUtc;
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "timezone_name")
    @JsonProperty("timezone_name")
    private String timezoneName;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_on",nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository()
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, String> {
}
```

Tried with `JpaRepository<Account, Long>` too and `flush` after saving..but still getting `id` null in return list response of `saveall()`

Service:

```
@Service
public class AccountsService {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository repository;
   

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Account> saveAll(List<Account> accounts) {
     //in case of JpaRepository
         List<Account> savedAccounts= repository.saveAll(accounts);
         repository.flush();
         return savedAccounts;
     //in case of CrudRepository
       return (List<Account>)repository.saveAll(accounts);
    }

}
```

when executing this

```
//accountsList received from FB API
List<Account> savedList=iAccountsService.saveAll(accountsList);
savedList.get(0).getId() **//this is coming as null**
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably related to `@JsonIgnore`? `insertable = false`? You are calling `saveAll()` after all

Comment: @OriDar `@Jsonignore` is for object-json mapping from jackson & even after removing `insertable=false` I am getting same issue.

Comment: It works if I annotate `id` with `@Id` but for my use case I want `account_id` to be primary key. I think for non primary key autogeneration there seems to be some issue.

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` is used with primary key. GeneratedValue Provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values of primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

In your entity class :

Use this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

```
public class Account implements Serializable{

    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

}
```